# Integrating a function forcing parameters to be real and positive

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'd like to integrate the function $f(x)=x^{a-1}e^{-b x}$ over the interval $[0,\infty)$.

```
f[x_] := x^(a - 1)*Exp[-b*x]
```

Then:

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

But I get:

```
ConditionalExpression[b^-a Gamma[a], Re[b] > 0 && Re[a] > 0]
```

How can I force both a and b to be real, positive parameters, then try the integration again?

Comment: `Assuming[Re[b] > 0 && Re[a] > 0, Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]]` Just copied what Integrate gave back into the Assuming part.

Comment: @Nasser looks like an answer...

Comment: It looks like a question asked instead of looking into documentation, does not it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to @Nasser´s solution you can also use the `Assumptions` option:

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> {Element[{a, b}, Reals], a > 0, b > 0}]
```

> ```
> b^-a Gamma[a]
> ```

As pointed out by @m_goldberg, the assumption of  `a > 0` and `b > 0` is sufficient, because this already implies real values.

Comment: Nice answers. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, `Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}]` is sufficient, since `{a > 0, b > 0}` implies `a` and `b` are real.

Comment: Another very nice answer.